# when does a array act as a pointer in c?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

i know that the array name could be used as a pointer(although it's a converted form), but my question is , Is there some other instance where array acts as a pointer.

Comment: Is this question about C or about C++? Please remove either of those tags as arrays act differently in those very different languages.

Comment: It seems to decay any time you sneeze in its general direction.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to ask here. Edit your questionto be more clear.

Comment: Answer here for C++: [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: @WTP:  While the languages are different, most of C90 works the same in C++ and C99 as it used to.  I don't know of any differences with arrays and array-to-pointer conversions.  Most of the differences are in usage, stuff you'd do differently in C and C++, and this isn't a usage question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Comment: @David: One difference is that in c++ arrays can be passed by reference into functions, retaining their size information.

Comment: The existing question cited by Chris Lutz has an excellent summary in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

Technically speaking, an array name never acts as a pointer.  An
expression with array type (which could be an array name) will convert
to a pointer anytime an array type is not legal, but a pointer type is.
And the declaration of an array as a function parameter is converted
into a declaration of a pointer.  (Which means that the name isn't an
array name, but a pointer name.  Despite appearances.)

Comment: @potrzebie In the expression `a++`, `a` converts to a pointer.  The result of the conversion is an rvalue, and the `++` operator requires an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to *array-to-pointer* standard conversion. Specifically, array decays into a pointer to the first element of the array.

Array decays into a pointer, I think, because arrays and pointers are used exactly in the same way: using an *index*, which you can increment and decrement, to traverse  the elements, in both direction, forward and backward..

Answer (score 1):

Here are the relevant sections of the [C language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (you asked for C, that's what you get):

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a
> string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is
> converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points to the initial element of
> the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the
> behavior is undefined.
> ...
> **6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**
> **Constraints**
> 1 One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to object *type*’’, the other expression shall
> have integer type, and the result has type ‘‘*type*’’.
> **Semantics**
> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]` is a subscripted
> designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator `[]`
> is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Because of the conversion rules that
> apply to the binary `+` operator, if `E1` is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
> initial element of an array object) and `E2` is an integer, `E1[E2]` designates the `E2`-th
> element of `E1` (counting from zero).
> ...
> **6.7.5.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
> ...
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
> *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
> actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many
> elements as specified by the size expression

The important thing to take away from this is that there is a difference between an object (in the C sense, something that takes up memory) and the expression we use to refer to that object.  Arrays are always arrays, but the *expression* used to refer to that object will often be of a pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

```
The identifier itself tells the base address of the memory block.

int arr[SIZE];

 arr
+------+------+----       ----+------+
|      |      |     . . .     |      |
+------+------+----       ----+------+
 arr[0] arr[1]  arr[2]  arr[n-1] arr[n]



The `arr' holds the address of the base address of the block

int *arr = malloc (sizeof (int) * SIZE);

 arr
+------+
|addr1 |------------+
+------+            |
addr_of_arr         |
                    |
                    |
                    V
                  +------+------+----       ----+------+
                  |      |      |     . . .     |      |
                  +------+------+----       ----+------+
                  addr1[0] addr[1]    addr1[n-1] addr1[n]
```

Answer (score -3):

Arrays in C are basically just pointers that reserve consecutive blocks of memory. So in essence arrays always act like pointers.

Comment: Arrays in C are arrays.  You're thinking of B.

Comment: Nope; try `int foo[3]; int * bar; printf("%d %d\n", (int)sizeof(foo), (int)sizeof(bar));`.