# using global array inside threads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

What I want is,
 If data in array `buff` inside the thread changes, the global variable `global_buff` data must also change

```
#include <process.h>
.........

char global_buff_1[50];
char global_buff_2[50];

void thread (int x)
{
   char buff[50] = {0};
   if (x == 0)
      buff = global_buff_1;      //this is what i need, how can i equal two array correctly. i want to if buff array data changing the global_buff also changing.
   else
      buff = global_buff_2;
    .............
    //do some thing 
    .............
}

int main(int argc, char* argv [])
{
...................
int y = 0;
_beginthread((void(*)(void*))thread, 0, (void*)y);
.....................
}
```

any helping!

Comment: I am really finding it hard to Understand what is your problem here. Can you frame your words in such a way, that it is understandable to us?

Comment: C or C++, not both. `buff = global_buff_2` How do you expect assigning a `char` to an array to work?

Answer (score 1):

```
void thread (int x)
{
   char* buff = 0; // change here to a pointer 
   if (x == 0)
      buff = global_buff_1; // new these assignments work. And when changing buff
   else                     // global_buff_1 and global_buff_2 will change depending on
      buff = global_buff_2; // the assignment done here
    .............
    //do some thing 
    .............
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to,

- assign `global_buff_1[]` to `buff[]`
- Reflect changes to `buff[]` array in `global_buff_1[]`

`buff` is a `char` array and [array name can act as pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690340/when-does-a-array-act-as-a-pointer-in-c) too. `global_buff_1` is a `char` array too.
So you can't simply assign an array to another array, since they are addresses. If you need to copy the value from `global_buff_1` to `buff` you need to do something like,

```
strcpy(buff,global_buff_1);
```

But this will create two separate arrays, with same values and won't satisfy your second requirement.

You can make use of pointers here as such,

```
char * buff;
buff = global_buff_1;
```

But  still you have a single array accessible by two *names*.

Comment: If you do a `memcpy` changing the local array will not change the global one.

Comment: @RedX ok. I think I get the question now. "changing of buff when global changes" Thanks for pointing out. Edit ahead!